# Assignment inside function that is passed as pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters

```
ClassA* pa = NULL;
ClassA* pb = NULL;

void assignObject(ClassA* pa, ClassB* pb) 
{
  pa = new ClassA;
  pb = new ClassB;
}
```

What will be the value of `pa` and `pb`  after executing the function?

EDIT
how to pass as pointer is the return if pa,pb is NULL

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As pointed out in other answers - both will still be NULL after the call. However, there are two possible solutions to this problem:

1) **references**

```
void assignObject(ClassA*& pa, ClassB*& pb)
{
    pa = new ClassA;
    pb = new ClassB;
}

ClassA* pa = NULL;
ClassA* pb = NULL;
assignObject(pa, pb); // both will be assigned as expected.
```

2) **pointers**

```
void assignObject(ClassA** pa, ClassB** pb)
{
    assert(pa != NULL); assert(pb != NULL);
    *pa = new ClassA;
    *pb = new ClassB;
}
ClassA* pa = NULL;
ClassA* pb = NULL;
assignObject(&pa, &pb); // both will be assigned as expected.
```

Most programmers would probably choose references because then they don't need to assert anything (references can never be NULL).

Answer (score 4):

They will be NULL, since you're passing them by value. If you want to pass it by reference, you'd do this:

```
ClassA* pa = NULL;
ClassA* pb = NULL;
assignObject(ClassA*& pa, ClassB*& pb)
{
    pa = new ClassA;
    pb = new ClassB;
}
```

Note, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the global variables. They're never used in this example, since the local variables (function parameters) hide them.

I think you also need to declare a return value type for your function in order for it to be valid C++.

Comment: the sample is just an example

Comment: @rajKumar: make sure you post valid code; otherwise, you can end up with misleading or even incorrect answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClassA* pa = NULL;
ClassA* pb = NULL;

void assignObject(ClassA* &pa,ClassB* &pb)
{
    pa = new ClassA;
    pb = new ClassB;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
ClassA* pa = NULL;
ClassA* pb = NULL;

void assignObject(ClassA** pa,ClassB** pb)
{
    *pa = new ClassA;
    *pb = new ClassB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL, because you're passing the pointers in by value.

Comment: Maybe you should change the question...?