# mock a function with pointer as argument

Tags: visual-c++, googlemock

I want to mock a function which has a pointer argument

```
class I_Shaft
{
public:
    virtual ~I_Shaft() {
    }
    virtual void GetFloor(I_Floor* FloorPointer) = 0;
};
```

the mocked interface:

```
class Mock_I_Shaft : public I_Shaft
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(GetFloor, void(I_Floor* FloorPointer));
};
```

the mocked interface Mock_I_Floor which needs a default and a copy constructor (otherwise it won't get compiled):

```
class Mock_I_Floor : public I_Floor
{
public:
    Mock_I_Floor() {}
    Mock_I_Floor(const Mock_I_Floor& f) {}
    virtual ~Mock_I_Floor() {};

    MOCK_METHOD0(GetPosition, uint16_t());
};
```

the implementation that is to be tested:

```
C_HZS::C_HZS(I_Shaft& refShaft) :  //constructor initializing refShaft
    refShaft(refShaft)
{
}

void C_HZS::run(void)
{
    I_Floor* ptrFloor = NULL;

    refShaft.GetFloor(ptrFloor);

    if(ptrFloor == NULL){
        std::cerr << "there is no valid pointer" <<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    floorPosition = ptrFloor->GetPosition();
    std::cout << "floorPosition: " << floorPosition << std::endl;
}
```

and here is my test:

```
TEST(HZS, testFloorPosition) {
    Mock_I_Shaft shaft;
    Mock_I_Floor floor;

    Mock_I_Floor* pFloorMocked= &floor;

    C_HZS dutObj(shaft);

    EXPECT_CALL(shaft, GetFloor(_))
        .Times(AtLeast(1))
        .WillOnce(SetArgPointee<0>(*pFloorMocked)
        );

    dutObj.run();
    EXPECT_FALSE(...);
}
```

The problem is: I am not able to inject pFloorMocked into the mocked function. Within the run() function ptrFloor always stays NULL. What is the reason for this? Is there another way to mock this function?

Comment: `ptrFloor` is always null because you are using a pointer passed by value (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416162/assignment-inside-function-that-is-passed-as-pointer).  You must use a pointer passed by reference, a pointer to a pointer, or just return a pointer from `GetFloor`.

Comment: I tried solution No. 1 from [Assignment inside function that is passed...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416162/assignment-inside-function-that-is-passed-as-pointer) and it works. Thanks for that. But I didn't understand why this is working!

Comment: I have to add, that the interface `I_Shaft` (that I mocked) is a real implemented interface. To get the solution from @RA. working, it is necessary to change the signature which is undesirable. Are there any other suggestions? Or is the original signature (pointer passed by value) actually wrong?