# How do I assign an object to passed nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, shared-ptr

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct MyObject {
  std::string name;
};

void getOrCreateMyObject(std::shared_ptr<MyObject> myObj) {
  if (myObj == nullptr) {
    myObj = std::make_shared<MyObject>();
    myObj->name = "Created Automatically";
  }
  std::cout << myObj->name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject> moPtr = nullptr;
  getOrCreateMyObject(moPtr);
  if (moPtr != nullptr) {
    std::cout << moPtr->name << std::endl;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing a `nullptr` to the function, where it checks for the `nullptr` and creates a `shared_ptr` and successfully uses the newly created object. However, returning back to `main`, the `moPtr` is still a `nullptr`.

So how do I make it so I can access that newly object outside the scope of that function?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Thank you everybody. Changing the code to

`void getOrCreateMyObject(std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& myObj)`

did, of course, work. Somehow I wrongly assumed that passing the pointer automatically resolves to the outer pointer when leaving the function.

Comment: You're passing `myObj` as a copy. If you want the code in `getOrCreateMyObject` to modify the instance from `main`, you can pass a reference instead.

Comment: Consider looking this page too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416162/assignment-inside-function-that-is-passed-as-pointer

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<MyObject>` works exactly like all other types, as do actual pointers. Since the argument is not a reference, any modifications to it have no effect outside the function. (Would you expect `getOrCreateMyObject(nullptr);` to change the value of `nullptr`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to this [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parameter-passing-techniques-in-c-cpp/):

There are **two** parameter-passing modes in C++: by value,and by reference.

- When a parameter is passed **by value**, ***the changes made to the parameter within the function do not affect the value of the actual argument used in the function call***.
- When a parameter is passed by reference, changes made to the parameter do affect the actual arguments in the client space. In addition, there is a special mode of passing array parameters.

So you are passing your parameter by value, which means any changes inside the callee function scope will affect **only** the copied instance of passed parameter.

Comment: There are two; values and references. There is no difference between pointers and other values. (geeksforgeeks is notoriously awful.)

Comment: To make things a bit clearer, a pointer _is_ a kind of reference in the first place. So the question is whether to pass the pointer by value (just a pointer) or by reference (a pointer or reference to pointer).