# Storing and using smart_ptr address

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm trying to pass a `shared_ptr` to an object around, which may or may not be null:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct MyObject {
  int i = 0;
  MyObject(const int i_) : i(i_) {}
};

struct Command {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject> cmdObj;

  Command(std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& obj) : cmdObj(obj) {
    std::cout << "Store and use this address: " << &obj << std::endl;  // [1]
  }

  void execute() {
    if (cmdObj == nullptr) {
      cmdObj = std::make_shared<MyObject>(42);
    } else {
      cmdObj->i = 7;
    }
  }
};

struct CommandManager {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject> globalObj;  // [1]

  CommandManager() { globalObj = nullptr; }

  void runCommand() {
    Command cmd(globalObj);
    cmd.execute();
  }
};

int main() {
  CommandManager cm;
  std::cout << "cm.globalObj address: " << &cm.globalObj << std::endl;  // [1]
  cm.runCommand();
  if (cm.globalObj == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "globalObj is null" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "globalObj is " << cm.globalObj->i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to manipulate or create `globalObj` from within `Command`. However, despite passing the address in the constructor (`[1]`), I'm not storing it correctly so that the new object is usable in the `CommandManager`.

How do I make it so I can store and use the address of the `shared_ptr<MyObject>` correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't understand the question. Could you show the output and explain what is wrong there.

Comment: To store an address, you need a pointer. In this case, a pointer to a `std::shared_ptr`. Though I'm not sure you actually want a `std::shared_ptr` to begin with.

Comment: `Command` modifies its class member. Have you considered simply updating `globalObj` by retrieving it from the `Command`, after `execute()`?

Comment: Regarding `"Store and use this address: " << &obj"`. You may be confusing the address of the pointer with the address the pointer points to. A pointer is an object and has its own address which is distinct from its value, which is also an address, that of the object it points to. `&obj` is the address of the pointer. For smart pointers `obj.get()` is the address of the object it points to. Each `shared_ptr` necessarily has its own address (a different value of `&obj`) even when they point to the same object.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the confusion, but I'll give it a try:
`cmdObj` and `globalObj` are not connected by default. If `Command::execute` creates a new `shared_ptr` and assigns it to `cmdObj`, then this does not change `globalObj`, because the "shared" instance would be the object that the shared point is pointing to, not the shared pointer itself.

Comment: @Cedric: will ````cmdObj```` be destroyed, when Command  goes out of scope ? or will ````globalObj```` prevent that ? I'm confused...

Comment: @nick : yes. I would suggest adding a custom constructor and destructor to `MyObject` with prints so you see when this happens.
When you pass `globalObj` to the constructor, `cmdObj` is copy constructed. This means that if `globalObj` were to contain a pointer to an object, then `cmdObj` would also point to the same `MyObject` instance and the reference is incremented. However, `make_shared` creates a new `shared_ptr` and replaces whatever was written in `cmdObj` (but only that one!). It does not affect `globalObj`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : Yes, that is how I'm doing it right now. However, I thought this is a rather cumbersome and inelegant approach, since it requires additional checks and assignments. I was hoping to simply be able to use `globalObj` from inside the `Command`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : Yes, `globalObj` and `cmdObj` have different addresses. I'm sure I'm being stupid, but I can't get it to work so that I can make use of the outer address (i.e. using the address of `globalObj` in the `Command` to store the reference to the newly created object there.

Comment: @nick : Exactly. Because `Command` might be destroyed, I want to keep the pointer to `MyObject` in the `CommandManager`.

Comment: Your Command object had a copy of the shared pointer. From the description, it sounds like you want the Command to have a *reference* to the manager's shared pointer. `std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& cmdObj;`

Comment: @RaymondChen : Yes, that's it. However, despite thinking that I understood it since I asked about it previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74356948/how-do-i-assign-an-object-to-passed-nullptr), I could not get it to work. I'm sure I tried one of Nelfeal's solutions (`std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& cmdObj`), but it didn't compile and actually did not when I changed it accordingly in VS2022. Only after rebuilding the solution did it work, which is not the first time that has happened. :/ On the other hand, I am sadly not very good at programming, so I am pretty sure it was my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store an address, you need a pointer. In this case, a pointer to a std::shared_ptr.

```
struct Command {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject>* cmdObj;

  Command(std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& obj) : cmdObj(&obj) {
    std::cout << "Store and use this address: " << &obj << std::endl;  // [1]
  }

  void execute() {
    if (*cmdObj == nullptr) {
      *cmdObj = std::make_shared<MyObject>(42);
    } else {
      (*cmdObj)->i = 7;
    }
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Pcs5cTj8)

You can also use a reference here since you need to pass something to `Command`'s constructor, and a you won't have a dangling reference problem unless you'd have a dangling pointer problem with the previous option.

```
struct Command {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& cmdObj;

  Command(std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& obj) : cmdObj(obj) {
    std::cout << "Store and use this address: " << &obj << std::endl;  // [1]
  }

  void execute() {
    if (cmdObj == nullptr) {
      cmdObj = std::make_shared<MyObject>(42);
    } else {
      cmdObj->i = 7;
    }
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/evvqbsMYn)

However, I'm not sure you actually want a `std::shared_ptr` to begin with. A simple variable would work just as well.

```
struct Command {
  MyObject* cmdObj;

  Command(MyObject* obj) : cmdObj(obj) {
    std::cout << "Store and use this address: " << obj << std::endl;  // [1]
  }

  void execute() {
      cmdObj->i = 7;
  }
};

struct CommandManager {
  MyObject globalObj = 42;  // [1]

  void runCommand() {
    Command cmd(&globalObj);
    cmd.execute();
  }
};

int main() {
  CommandManager cm;
  std::cout << "cm.globalObj address: " << &cm.globalObj << std::endl;  // [1]
  cm.runCommand();
  std::cout << "globalObj is " << cm.globalObj.i << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v7xfx8xnc)

If your original intent was to share the `MyObject` object through a `std::shared_ptr`, then you need to create that object before you can share it.

```
struct Command {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject> cmdObj;

  Command(std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& obj) : cmdObj(obj) {
  }

  void execute() {
      cmdObj->i = 7;
  }
};

struct CommandManager {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject> globalObj;  // [1]

  CommandManager() { globalObj = std::make_shared<MyObject>(42); }

  void runCommand() {
    Command cmd(globalObj);
    cmd.execute();
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E9svEnEe5)

Or you can create it in `Command` and then share it with `CommandManager`.

```
struct Command {
  std::shared_ptr<MyObject> cmdObj;

  Command(std::shared_ptr<MyObject>& obj) {
    if (obj == nullptr) {
        obj = std::make_shared<MyObject>(42);
    }
    cmdObj = obj;
  }

  void execute() {
    cmdObj->i = 7;
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jhTMK6oKM)

Or you can create a `std::unique_ptr`, share it, and then create the `MyObject` object in `Command` if needed.

```
struct Command {
  std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> cmdObj;

  Command(std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> obj) : cmdObj(obj) {
  }

  void execute() {
    if (*cmdObj == nullptr) {
      *cmdObj = std::make_unique<MyObject>(42);
    } else {
      (*cmdObj)->i = 7;
    }
  }
};

struct CommandManager {
  std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> globalObj;  // [1]

  CommandManager() { globalObj = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>>(nullptr); }

  void runCommand() {
    Command cmd(globalObj);
    cmd.execute();
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nEaYoY77a)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time writing all of this up!!! The first two are what I was looking for and couldn't get to work.  Regarding your other solutions: I do need a pointer, since the object may (or may not) be loaded from a file etc., so I can't be sure it exists or will ever be created. Certainly, I can't create it in the `CommandManager`, since it does not have the neccessary information to do so (the `Command` gets the info from a JSON object). I'm sure an experience programmer can make it more elegantly, but I'm afraid that is beyond the scopy of SO and my abilities. Thank you again!

Comment: @Markstar The last two examples also allow you to create the object in `Command`. Though if the intent is to have `CommandManager` keep sole ownership of the object, then just don't use a `std::shared_ptr`: replace it with a `std::unique_ptr` in either of the first two examples.

Comment: Hmm, in the second last example, the object is created during the initialization, which is too early. If I understand the last example correctly, the `CommandManager` creates a dummy object so that it can then be used in `Command`? I don't quite understand. But I think I will go with your 2nd solution, which makes the mose sense to me. :)

Comment: @Markstar If the object must be created in `Commad::execute`, then yes the second to last example doesn't work. The last example just solves the problem by introducing an additional layer of abstraction. To share an object with `std::shared_ptr`, it must contain an object. So instead of not having a `MyObject` at the beginning, it now contains a `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>` that is itself empty. Then what's shared is that `std::unique_ptr`, not the `MyObject`. It would also work with a `std::optional` instead of a `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: a reference is not an address, despite using the same `&` character that is used for the address-of operator. I assume that you are talking about references, not addresses.

You pass a `globalObj` reference to the constructor, however the only reference there is the formal parameter `obj`.

You print the address of `obj` and verify that it is the same as the address of `globalObj`, which is expected. *But `cmdObj` is not `obj`.*

`cmdObj` is an object, not a reference. Initialising it will create a copy of whatever you initialising it from, completely unlinked from the original. Its address is different, and you can print it and see for yourself.

Changing `cmdObj` (the copy) will not affect `globalObj` (the original) in any way, shape, or form.

```
if (cmdObj == nullptr) {  
  // Before the assignment, globalObj was nullptr.
  cmdObj = std::make_shared<MyObject>(42);
  // And it still is after the assignment to cmdObj.
```

You can make `cmdObj` a reference too:

```
Mystd::shared_ptr<MyObject>Object*& cmdObj;
```

and this will likely have the effect you want.

Note, I am not talking about the object(s) *pointed to* by any of these smart pointers. Just about the pointers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal program which displays the difference between `shared_ptr` lifetime and lifetime of the object they point to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {

  // Create an integer, give shared ownership to sp_1
  std::shared_ptr<int> sp_1 = std::make_shared<int>(2);

  // sp_2 points to same integer now, so sp_2.get() == sp_1.get().
  // Reference count is increased to 2.
  // Note that sp_1 and sp_2 are still different objects, i.e. &sp_2 != &sp_1 
  std::shared_ptr<int> sp_2 = sp_1;

  // Value of int is changed (both sp_1 and sp_2 point to it)
  *sp_2 = 4;

  // Replace shared_ptr object sp_2. It now points to another integer object.
  // sp_1 is not affected by it, the reference count to the first integer is back down to 1.
  sp_2 = std::make_shared<int>(6);

  std::cout << *sp_1 << " is still 4!" << std::endl;
  std::cout << *sp_2 << " is 6!" << std::endl;

  // "Destroy" first integer object
  sp_1.reset();

  // This is perfectly valid since sp_2 is pointing to a different integer
  *sp_2 = 8;
  std::cout << *sp_2 << " is 8!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Run it here: https://godbolt.org/z/qMKvzzbWE